# Xmpp user login authentication from another database

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm new in XMPP, recently I have installed and configure openfire admin control by defining IP (localhost), port (5222) and new database named: **openfire** in MySql.

But my usernames and their passwords are in another database, is there any steps to configure in openfire so that it can check the user authentication in my own created database instead of checking it's(openfire) own created usertable **ofuser**.

I'am Adding TAGS here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    This file stores bootstrap properties needed by Openfire.
    Property names must be in the format: "prop.name.is.blah=value"
    That will be stored as:
        <prop>
            <name>
                <is>
                    <blah>value</blah>
                </is>
            </name>
        </prop>

    Most properties are stored in the Openfire database. A
    property viewer and editor is included in the admin console.
-->
<!-- root element, all properties must be under this element -->
<jive> 
  <adminConsole> 
    <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->  
    <port>9099</port>  
    <securePort>9091</securePort> 
  </adminConsole>  
  <locale>en</locale>  
  <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
      Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
      will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
       on multi-homed servers. -->  
  <!--
    <network>
        <interface></interface>
    </network>
    -->  
  <connectionProvider> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  
  <database> 
    <defaultProvider> 
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
      <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</serverURL>  
      <username encrypted="true">87d776abae54f5b4c95c78b78420a6967a9429e9e6d7a5c0</username>  
      <password encrypted="true">7a1603cafdfe1383ea0e284360172ca8c94b37314dbd5390</password>  
      <testSQL>select 1</testSQL>  
      <testBeforeUse>false</testBeforeUse>  
      <testAfterUse>false</testAfterUse>  
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>  
      <maxConnections>25</maxConnections>  
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout> 
    </defaultProvider> 
  </database>  
  <jdbcProvider> 
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
    <connectionString>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root;password=root</connectionString> 
  </jdbcProvider>  
  <provider> 
    <auth> 
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider</className> 
    </auth>  
    <user> 
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider</className> 
    </user> 
  </provider>  
  <jdbcAuthProvider> 
    <passwordSQL>SELECT upwd FROM users WHERE uname=? and usertype=2 and delflag=0</passwordSQL>  
    <passwordType>md5</passwordType> 
  </jdbcAuthProvider>  
  <jdbcUserProvider> 
    <loadUserSQL>SELECT CONCAT(ufname,ulname) AS name,uemail as email FROM users WHERE uname=? AND usertype=2 AND delflag=0</loadUserSQL>  
    <userCountSQL>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE usertype=2 AND delflag=0 AND inactive=0</userCountSQL>  
    <allUsersSQL>SELECT uname FROM users WHERE usertype=2 AND delflag=0 AND inactive=0</allUsersSQL>  
    <searchSQL>SELECT uname FROM users WHERE usertype=2 AND delflag=0 AND inactive=0</searchSQL>  
    <usernameField>uname</usernameField>  
    <nameField>ufname</nameField>  
    <emailField>uemail</emailField> 
  </jdbcUserProvider>  
  <setup>true</setup> 
</jive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a official openfire documentation for exact your case:

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html

Comment: I have gone through with all the steps using above URL, I'm able to start openfire but still it is not showing or authenticating other users. No error or logs I found during startup.

Comment: I have added conf/openfire.xml on the main Question let me know if anything is wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, editing openfire.xml wont make any expected change with your openfire. even after you restart it.

You should edit that configuration from SERVER -> System Properties . OR you can directly modify database in ofproperty values.

but be carefull.. none of my JDBC authentication seems work if use my own user table. even if i set it to PLAIN password. and their MD5 looks different than standart md5 hashing method